# How to justify empty divs in flex container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 div, Sometimes all of them have text inside but sometimes some of them were empty. If first div is an empty I need second and third div floating left. But Always it stay at end, first div's place remains an empty.

I tried justify-content-start and giving a margin-right to child divs but it also doesn't work.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-around expert-detail">
   <div>
   </div>

   <div>
   </div>

   <div>
      some text
   </div>
</div>
```

I need something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with this code.

```
div:empty { display: none }
```